# Send command from TIdCmdTCPServer

Tags: windows, c++builder, indy10

I am receiving commands from a client in TIdCmdTCPServer and this works great. Now I want to send events to the client, but I cannot seem to find any place to do this. I know how to do it in TIdTCPServer, but like the clean code its Cmd equivalent gives me. How/where do I inject a text for the client?
What I've tried so far is look for a receiver thread from where I can send commands (the equivalent of TIdCmdServer's Execute thread), or something like a SendCmd, but have not found anything. Starting to wonder if this is even possible?

Comment: Hard to say for sure without knowing the design of your server and protocol. There are a few different ways you can approach this.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm not aware there is more than one way to use TidCmdTCPServer? I'm using it straight out the book: setup IO handlers for each command and process there. Is there anything else you need to know?

Comment: yes, I need to know the design of your communication protocol and how it deals with unsolicited events in relation to commands/responses, and I need to know how you would implement this using TIdTCPServer instead for your protocol. Like I said, there are different ways you can approach this issue depending on your current design. You could hook into TIdCmdTCPServer to send events between it reading commands. You can manually use command handlers in TIdTCPServer instead of TIdCmdTCPServer. You can use a dedicated event sending thread if you sync it with sending command responses.

Comment: @Remylebeau I already have designed the second option so know how to do that, but didn't want to redo the code I'm working on now. Was really looking for a similar way (your first suggestion) but haven't found any way to hook into the reading thread.

Comment: you can derive from TIdCmdTCPServer and override its virtual ReadCommandLine() method. The inherited method reads a line from the socket and passes it to the CommandHandlers collection for processing. You could have your override send events in between command readings as needed

Comment: Exactly what I need, thanks! Make it an answer so I can mark it.